# Use of "if", "whether" or "did" in a question

Tags: questions, whether-if

I had to send an email to a colleague from work to make sure I am registered to some kind of company event.

I wasn't sure what is the best grammar to go with. Options that are considered are:

> 1. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me if I am registered already?
> 2. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me whether I am registered already?
> 3. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me am I registered already?
> 4. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me did I register already?

I went with option number 2. Which one would native speaker choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 are perfect - 'if' and 'whether' are interchangeable in this context. A native speaker would use either of these, although if using whether you are more likely to follow the phrase with 'or not', as below:

> 2. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me whether **or not** I am registered already?

Options 3 and 4 would benefit from some punctuation, but still make sense:

> 3. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me, am I registered already?
> 4. Sorry to bother you, could you tell me, did I register already?